# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1920991232 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, csv, memory-limit

I wrote some code in PHP to read CSV a file:

```
while (!feof($file_handle)) 
{
    $csv=fgetcsv($file_handle, 10024);
    if(is_array($csv))
    {
        $csv=array_slice($csv, 1);
        $csvfile[]=$csv;
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1920991232 bytes exhausted (tried to allocat
>   e 10025 bytes)

I added `ini_set('memory_limit', '10024M');` this line starting of the code and I increased `memory_limit` in php.ini file also, but it's giving the same error.

Can anybody help?

Comment: You're absolutely certain that reading/parsing the complete file to an array before processing the data is necessary?

Comment: Except that i would not load the whole file into memory, check if you have `suhosin` installed or compiled with `suhosin` enabled, if yes check if this is limiting your memory.

Comment: @volkery: I am reading line by line and putting it into array so that i can use that array later and file size is 20MB.

Comment: @t.niese. Can you please tell me how to check if suhosin is installed or no or complied with suhosin?

Comment: e.g. check the output of php info and search there for `suhosin`

Answer (score 3):

Note that to have no memory limit, set this directive to -1.
`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Then restart apache and try;)

Comment: Hey great catch. I didn't even think to do this. One note though, the code is in PHP, so there isn't a need to restart Apache when doing this.